# CakePHP pages without controller in url

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Is it possible to have pages route without the controller in the URL but still have other controllers work? Example:

- Access pages like this: http://domain.com/about/
- Instead of like this: http://domain.com/pages/about/
- But still have access to http://domain.com/othercontroller/action/

Doing the following works for having the pages without /pages/ in the URL but if I try to access any other controller it doesn't work:

- From: `Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));`
- To: `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'index'));`

Is there a way to setup the Router so that it runs controller/action if it exists. If it does not it runs the pages controller/action?

Comment: I'm wrapping my head around your question and still cant quite get it. You would like to match 2 different controllers /w actions with one URL? Btw you should know what actions are available to you and create routes accordingly. From the last line of your question I imagine that you have URL which contains controller and action, right? And if it does not exists you want to run some action from pages controller? Well you see, I really cant make any sense from this so if you explain it somehow to me I might be able to help you.

Comment: @luboss Thanks for your involvement and I apologize for my lack of clarity. Basically I want pages to be accessible at http://domain.com/pagename/ but creating a route for that means that if I try to access a controller it won't work because it thinks the controller is a page. Example: For http://domain.com/users/edit/1 Cake would think users is a page rather than a controller.... For now I went with Dave's answer. I don't think there's really a "solution". The only way is to explicitly tell Cake which routes are pages.

Comment: Ok I get it now. I think the ability to match parameters via regular expressions is the best you can get so yes you did right. However if you define route like this 
`Router::connect('/:pagename', array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display'));` and in display action you grab the parameter like this `$pagename = $this->params->pagename;` the other url (domain.com/users/edit/1) would remain unaffected because it has extra bits that arent covered in just defined route (/edit/1) this way you dont have to enumerate page names as long as you dont have conflicting url matches.

Comment: Of course it would affect URL when trying to access index function of some controller like domain.com/users instead of domain.com/users/index but you can solve this by putting something unique in your defined pages route or differentiate it by giving that url an .html extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the short answer is, no - it's not possible in the manner you're hoping*.  Routing isn't really "logic" driven, so unless you can come up with a way to match the things you want in both respects you can't do "if controller exists, then **_, else _**" kind of thing.

*You could, however add each "page" as a row in your routes file.  That would allow "about", "contact" ...etc to be accessed directly, while things that don't exactly match them are handled by the remaining routes.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is true, afaik, the default routes are compiled by CakePHP to match all available controller/action routes, so if the custom route is defined *after* the default routes, it should 'fall through' and will be handled by the custom route?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I went with explicitly defining which pages I have. @thaJeztah I think the issue is that cake thinks that the controller is the pagename instead of ignoring the pages rule. See my comment the question for more details.

Comment: @thaJeztah - I think the problem is, it WILL "match" as a controller/action (string/string), then it will look for that Controller and error when it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late, but here's my tip for someone looking for this.

In `routes.php`

```
foreach(scandir('../View/Pages') as $path){
  if(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "ctp"){
    $name = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    Router::connect('/'.$name, array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', $name));
  }
}
```

This will create a route for every ctp file in the View/Pages folder.

Comment: doesn't work if you are using themes. Those ones: book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this the opposite way from Dave's answer above, by adding a route for each controller, rather than each page. (I won't be adding new controllers very often, but I will be adding new content on a regular basis.)

```
// define an array of all controllers that I want to be able to view the index page of
$indexControllers = array('posts','events','users');

//create a route for each controller's index view
foreach ($indexControllers as $controller) {
    Router::connect(
        '/' . $controller,
        array(
            'controller' => $controller,
            'action' => 'index'
        )
    );
}

//create a route to remove 'view' from all page URLs
Router::connect(
    '/:title',
    array(
        'controller' => 'contents',
        'action' => 'view'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('title'),
        'title' => '[a-z0-9_\-]*'
    )
);
```